# How can this expression be simplified?

Tags: polynomials

How do I factorize $$a^{2}(b-c)+b^{2}(c-a)+c^{2}(a-b)?$$ 
I've tried it in different ways but failed. Wish some one could help solving it out.

Comment: As a start: If you take $a=b$ then the expression becomes $0$, and so $(a-b)$ is a factor of the expression. Similarly, $(b-c)$ and $(c-a)$ are also factors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*A high school solution:*

For this you have to break the symmetry between all variables. Explicitly, we'll write $\;c-a=(c-b)+(b-a)$. Thus
\begin{align*}
a^2(b-c)+b^2(c-a)+c^2(a-b)&=ab(a-b)+bc(b-c)+ca(c-a)\\
&=ab(a-b)+bc(b-c)+ca(c-b)+ca(b-a)\\
&=(a-b)(ab-ac)+(b-c)(bc-ac)\\
&=a(a-b)(b-c)+c(b-c)(b-a)\\
&=-(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)
\end{align*}

Comment: $c-a = (c-b)+(b-a)$

Comment: I've just seen that. Thanks for pointing the typo!

Answer (score 13):

If we think of this as a polynomial in the variable $a$, it is $0$ if $a=b$, also if $a=c$. So $a-b$ and $a-c$ divide the polynomial. By symmetry $b-c$ divides the polynomial. So the polynomial should be equal to $(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$ times a constant. In this case the constant is $1$.

Answer (score 5):

A simplification of André's answer:

The expression is a quadratic polynomial in $a$ that vanishes when $a=b$ or $a=c$.
The leading coefficient is clearly $b-c$.
Hence the expression is $(b-c)(a-b)(a-c)$.

Comment: An improvement! My initial writeup kept full symmetry to the end ($a-b$ divides, so does $b-c$, so does $c-a$, constant is $-1$). Then I partly broke symmetry, but breaking a little more is better.

Answer (score 2):

Another proof. By Laplace expansion (along the last row):

$$ -\sum_{cyc}a^2(b-c) = \det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ a & b & c \\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \end{pmatrix},\tag{1}$$
But the RHS is a Vandermonde matrix, whose determinant is well-known.

Gaussian elimination gives:
$$ D=\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ a & b & c \\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ a & b-a & c-a \\ a^2 & b^2-a^2 & c^2-a^2 \end{pmatrix} \tag{2}$$
and by expanding along the first row and factoring out $(b-a)$ and $(c-a)$:
$$ D = (b-a)(c-a)\cdot \det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ b+a & c+a\end{pmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b).\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

I think you meant factorization

$$a^2(b-c)+b^2(c-a)=-c(a^2-b^2)+ab(a-b)=?$$

Comment: Yeah. I meant factorization.